# open jquery dialog from php redirect error

Tags: php, jquery, dialog

I am having trouble opening a jquery window from a redirect after a database update. When the page redirects, I have coded so that I can get the value and open window based on that value. Example below.

```
header("Location: http://localhost/sample/users/cp.php?dialog=1");
exit();
```

In cp.php I have the following code which does not trigger window. If however, I change autoOpen:true, the the window loads on page load. I would be grateful if someone could point out my error. Thanks

cp.php

```
<?php
$dialog = $_GET['dialog'];
if ($dialog ==1)
        {
           echo '<script type="text/javascript"> dialog(); </script>';
        }

?>
<script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ui.dialog.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  function dialog() {
    $(function() {
        $( "#response1" ).dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            buttons: {
                Ok: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });


    });
  }
    </script>


 <div style="display:none" id="response1" title="Successfully updated destroy date">
    <p>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 50px 0;"></span>
        You have successfully updated your destroy date. You may now close this window. Thank you.
    </p>

</div>
```

Comment: You echo the script that calls `dialog()` before the script which declares that function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should upgrade JQuery and JQueryUI version.

Here is a suggestion :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    if(<?php echo ($dialog == 1) ? 'true' : 'false' ; ?>)
    {
        $( "#response1" ).dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: true,
            buttons: {
                Ok: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

This fiddle explain how to use your code : http://jsfiddle.net/2bxYW/

Comment: Thanks for reply. However, it errors with: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' on first line

Comment: now I am getting: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ',' or ';' in the if condition. thanks

Comment: Errored with: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDIF. thanks

Comment: Updated. Sorry, the reason of all these stupid errors is that I can't test with my laptop...

Comment: np. we have all been there:-) all I get now is a brief null message.

Comment: Are you sure that $dialog==1? Try to put $( "#response1" ).dialog('open'); after init code